# Unsure how to use properties of determinants to factorise a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, factoring

I'm unsure how I would factorise the following determinant

$$D =\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1& 1\\
\lambda& \mu& \upsilon\\
\lambda^2 & \mu^2 & \upsilon^2
\end{bmatrix}$$

I have found the determinant. However, I don't really know where to go from there. I do however feel that I am missing something here regarding the properties of determinants but I am unsure what that would be. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a [Vandemonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix). What do you mean by factorising it?

Comment: You surely mean factorize its determinant...

Comment: Sorry yeah I meant to factorise the determinant

Answer (score 1):

Hints : By column reduced operation, we have, $$D =\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0& 0\\
\lambda& \mu-\lambda& \upsilon-\lambda\\
\lambda^2 & \mu^2-\lambda^2& \upsilon^2-\lambda^2
\end{bmatrix}$$

Given matrix and this matrix have their dets equal.

(As the rule , if $A$ is a square matrix. Let $B$ be the square matrix obtained from $A$ by adding a row to another row, or by adding a column to another column. Then $det(A)=det(B) $)